# How can I adjust the relative width of columns and wrap columns of a dataframe when using streamlit?

Tags: css, pandas, streamlit

I have built a small data science web app using streamlit. One of the needs is to display a data frame, lets say

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import string
def gen_text():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=1000))

df = pd.DataFrame({'uploaded file': list('abcd'),
                   'relevance score': [0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8],
                   'length (tokens)': [10, 20, 30, 40],
                   'used in answer': list('yyny'),
                   'content': [gen_text() for _ in range(4)]})
```

I am using the following streamlit method

```py
st.dataframe(df.style.background_gradient(subset='relevance score', axis=None, vmin=0., vmax=1., cmap="YlGnBu"), use_container_width=True)
```

What else do I need to include in the style so that the columns have the width ratio 1:1:1:1:4 whatever is the overall width of the data frame in the app?

Additionally, I would like to wrap the last column named "content" so that I can see 2 lines of text. I do not want to change the actual content of the data frame (e.g. using textwrap). I would need to do these operations using styling.